# Updating a Place's lat/lon co-ordinates?

Tags: google-maps, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I have a Facebook Page which originally had one street address, but now has a new one.

I can change the street address within Facebook itself, but when I come to query the Graph API for the Page, the latitude & longitude are & have been for some time stuck on the old co-ordinates.

Is there a way to get Facebook to refresh the latitude & longitude to the new co-ordinates at all, either by using the Graph API or some other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating places or refreshing places cache is not available via the Facebook API.  I would [log a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) about the coordinates not getting updated via the graph api. You can [ask Facebook directly](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/) in their community forum.